# How to pass command line arguments in Jamfile?

Tags: jam

I want to execute a certain command `g++ <some cpp file>` in a Jamfile. However,  I want to take the name of the file as command line input. In bash, this can be done as follows

File `temp.sh` -

```
#!/bin/bash

g++ $1
```

And invoking it as `bash temp.sh <cpp file>`

I want to do the similar using jam by invoking `jam -fJamfile <cpp file>` on the terminal. How to do it? I tried searching for it but did not find any related information anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer.

Say the variable declared inside the jamfile is $(cppFile), run the jam as

`cppFile=<cpp file required> jam -fJamfile`